# How to deploy KrakenJs on my production server

Tags: node.js, kraken.js

I would like to deploy my KrakenJS project.
I used grunt to build the project and got the output in .build directory.
I am not really sure what to do from here. Should I package the full project and run it on the server using the npm start or is there anything else I should do with the build results.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Personnaly I'm using GIT to deploy app to production. It's fast and simple.

Some resources to automate deployment :

- http://davidtucker.net/articles/automating-with-grunt/
- http://codeplease.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/deploying-node-js-production/
- https://gist.github.com/mkoryak/5293127

Answer (score 0):

Yes: packing all that up and shipping it to the server is a perfectly reasonable deploy strategy.

Some people `npm shrinkwrap`; that's useful if you're willing to trust the npm registry to be up for deploys. `npm package` is useful, there, too.

A lot of people check a built tree into a release git repo -- that's not a bad strategy either, and allows delta-transmission of deploys, which is great.